How to enable vertical scrolling with flexible height?
I want to create a chat window, that has vertical scrolling if the content oveflows.
I have a flexbox containing 3 items. Title, The .chat chatbox and an input.
The .chat chatbox has Flex: 1; And I bellive it has to have Flex: 1 cause different screensizes.
(Althrough this is a school project, that will be shown on a single device ever. So no reall responsiveness nescesary.)
When I overflow the .chat container it just stretches.
If i set max-height: 500px; to the .chat container it oweflows, but I need it to fill the space between the two flex items.
I'm not sure, how far in the HTML should I go... It's a pretty big React project.
I will post only the section with the problem and can link to the whole code if nescesary.
EDIT: Here is the whole project if for context.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t7fNQKY2ZVbSgQ-GqqfxbHSbrcYRJFzO/view
Screenshot of the whole app: https://imgur.com/a/5zKc9qJ
    <div className='Clara-wrapper'>
         <div className='chat-side'>
            <div className='chat-info'>
              <p className='chat-title'>
                Currently chatting with: <span>Clara</span>
              </p>
            </div> { /* Chat info */ }

            <div className='chat'>
                <p className='assistant'>This is a Long message ................. </p>
                <p className='user'>This is a message</p>
                <p className='assistant'>This is a second message</p>
                <p className='assistant'>This is a Long message ................. </p>
                <p className='user'>This is a message</p>
                <p className='assistant'>This is a Long message ................. </p>
                <p className='assistant'>This is a second message</p>
                <p className='user'>This is a message</p>
                <p className='assistant'>This is a second message</p>
            </div> { /* Chat respones */ }

            <div className='chat-input'>
              <div className='input-container'>
                <input id='ai-input' placeholder='Message Clara...'/>
                <div className='send' title='Send message'></div>
              </div>
            </div> { /* Chat input */ }

          </div> { /* Chat side */ }

          <div className='face-side'>
           { /* Other side content */ }
          </div> { /* Face side */ }

        </div> { /* Clara Wrapper */ }

.Clara-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 53px 40px 27px 40px;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 52% auto;
    grid-template-rows: 1;
    gap: 15px;
}

.Clara .chat-side {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}


/* chat */
.Clara .chat {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    border-radius: var(--clara-border-radius);
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1; 
}

.Clara .chat::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(29, 33, 32, 0.8), rgba(29, 33, 32, 0));
}

.Clara .chat > p {
    width: fit-content;
    max-width: 75%;
    border-radius: var(--clara-border-radius);
    background-color: var(--clara-dark-1);
    padding: var(--clara-padding-chat);
    box-shadow: var(--clara-button-shadow);
}

.Clara .chat .assistant {
    background-color: var(--clara-main);
    margin-left: auto;
}




can you share me your project to solve  that problem?

@Edward Thomas Here is a link to the whole project with all packages.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t7fNQKY2ZVbSgQ-GqqfxbHSbrcYRJFzO/view?usp=sharing

Do you want to fill space between two flex items?

I dowloaded and installed ,run project.

Yes, I would like to fill the space between the two flex items. If you have any idea how to do it differently than with Flex: 1; that would work too. I can always just set a static height, but that would mess up scaling on the page. And I'm not sure what kind of zoom ratio will the app have in the end. Maybe 100%, maybe 90% or 80%. It will all depend on the screen size I will have my project presented at.

I answered about filling space. let's discuss about the static height. Explain what you want again.

Okay so I’ll say try setting the parent flex container to flex-direction: column. And after that, set flex: 1 to the chat container to occupy the available vertical space.
What has worked for me in the past for vertical scrolling was setting overflow-y: auto so try using that on the chat container.
Really hope that helps :)

Im 99% sure thats what I have in my code. Could have done some typo or missed something tho

It should work fine then, maybe try checking for typos.

Recently had a problem which almost made me lose my mind and it turned out that, I had a letter P somewhere it wasn’t suppose to be

Well I did check it many times. I also ran it through chat gpt and it says I don't have anything wrong with the code and it should work like that.

Then we need to maybe take another approach, did you maybe try putting the code in ChatGPT, asking it to give you other ways to write the code but maintaining the result you want. Try that and see.

Put in your original code, tell it the problem you’re facing and when it gives you an answer, see what was changed and you could also tell it to write the code in so many other ways, I know CHATGPT most times isn’t correct but from the options it provides you should be able to get a syntax that would work. Let me know how it goes :)

Yep, tried it, ChatGPT keeps repeating this code saying it should work. I even created a seperate HTML file to isolate the problem and it still does not work. He gave me some other ways using absolute positioning but that doesnt work also, the container with absolute position cant be scrolled.

.Clara-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 53px 40px 27px 40px;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 52% auto;
    grid-template-rows: 1;
}

Put this code. If you use this, I am sure you can fill the space between two flex items.
